# How to access SQLite database inside a zip file - android

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I have 180 MB SQLite database. If I compress it, it will be just around 40 MB.
I keep the file in asset folder and there's no problem in apk size as it is compressed in apk.

But when I copy the db file from the asset folder to phone memory or SD card, then it's 180 MB.

So, is there any way to use compressed db file in android?

Comment: instead of sqlite, try using Realm. check https://realm.io/

Comment: No, you can only work with an uncompressed file.

Comment: Did you ever manage to solve this?

Comment: Hello, how was it? Did you solved it?

Answer (score 0):

As opposed to having this database in the APK itself, I would suggest either:

- Putting the database onto a server, and selectively querying the server for records only as needed;
- Putting the database *file* onto a server, and having the application download it to the device's SD card when it is needed.

That said, you could hypothetically whip something up with [`GZIPInputStream`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/zip/GZIPInputStream.html) if you really want to go down your current path.

Comment: This is an offline dictionary type app. 

If I download the db file from the server to the device's SD card, then it'll take 180 MB and this is the problem actually. I have no problem with the apk size as it's already compressed.